# algorithm to control intensities of multiple lights

Tags: algorithm

We have multiple lights in 10x10 grid each of which we can control intensity 1 to 10. Target of those lights is a wall and our goal is to have uniform intensity within some range over wall image where user defines the intensity value.  One restriction is that only direct adjacent neighbor lights of given light will be affect the image intensity for the wall area the light directly shed on.

I think (and hope) that this is a known problem but couldn't find any good reference to solve this problem. Any tip or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Would the light intensity be uniform if all lamps are turned to the same intensity?  Also, what is the affect of a lamp on the light intensity on the wall directly targeted by an adjacent lamp?

Comment: I would think the same light intensity would achieve uniformity but it does not in reality. Always center area is brighter than edge areas. About lamp, it has narrow beam so that only adjacent lamps can affects each other in terms of image intensity.

Comment: The edge might be less bright as there are less neighboring lamps around (especially at the corners).  To get a definitive answer (which I might not give), you should tell us how _specificly_ the lamps affect the lights of their neighbors (e.g. does it double, increase it by 10%).  Also, in real life the fact that the beams are narrow still might allow some effect on neighbors-of-neighbors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that resulting intensity is linear combination of some neigbour lamps. For example, I[x,y]=a*L[x,y]+b*(L[x-1,y]+L[x+1,y]+L[x,y-1]+L[x,y-1])+c*(L[x-1,y-1] +...), where a,b,c are some coefficients. So there is linear system of 100 equations with 100 unknowns variables. It may be solved, if coefficients are known.

More complex model  - convolution of lamp intensity matrix with point spread function. It  may require sophisticated methods of signal reconstruction

Answer (score 0):

This cries out for a genetic algorithms approach:  Without too much trouble you can customize it to take into account your lamp characteristics, and any desired function of illumination on the wall.

*Update:*  To be more concrete, if the OP already has some information about the light intensity function due to one lamp, then the programming aspect will be tedious, but straightforward.  If not, then what's needed is a way to get that information.  One way to do this is to get a photodiode and just measure the light intensity from the center to the periphery, with one lamp turned on mounted the way it will be in the real application.  Use whatever sampling interval seems appropriate based on the physical set-up-- an inch, six inches, a foot, whatever.  Using that information, the OP can create a function of light intensity based on one lamp.

I have no particular photodiode to recommend, but they can't be that expensive, since Lego Mindstorms can take readings from them.  I did speak incorrectly in the comments below, though-- it might actually take one measurement for each of the ten intensity settings on the lamps, and I'm explicitly assuming that all the lamps have roughly the same performance.

From there, we can mathematically build the larger function of a light intensity pattern caused by 100 lamps at arbitrary intensities-- a function into which we can plug 100 numbers (representing the lamp settings) and get out a good approximation of the resulting light intensity.  Finally, we can use a genetic algorithm to optimize the inputs of *that* function such that uniform intensity patterns are highly fit.

Careful, though-- the true optimum of that statement is probably "all lamps turned off."

(If you're more confident in your photography than I am, a camera might work.  But either way, without a detailed knowledge of the intensity patterns of the lamp settings, this is not a solvable problem.)

Comment: You could solve this problem in genetic algorithm but it will really take long time and lots of image captures to find an optimum with given user-specified value.

Comment: No image captures involved.  One good measurement of the intensity pattern of one lamp, and a lot of calculations.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you but then how do you measure image intensities even with one lamp without image acquisition?